# Linux terminal: pass the answer(or arg values) in advance when installing package?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

When I run a command like `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048`, it asks me:

```
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/root/.ssh/id_rsa):
```

I'd like to write the path in advance and tried like this: `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 | cat '/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub'`.

But this doesn't work....

How can I do this?

Comment: That's like this cool place to get information from called man pages, like [man ssh-keygen](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ssh-keygen.1.html) tell us that `-f output_keyfile` might be really interesting to you. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/69314/automated-ssh-keygen-without-passphrase-how

Comment: @KamilCuk Hi that could be the solution. But `ssh-keygen` is just an example. I'd like to know how to concatenate the commands

Comment: Maybe you should consider [expect](https://likegeeks.com/expect-command/),
it allows you to interact with command, just use expect/send in your script.

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt was in reverse, meaning you were trying to pass the output of `ssh-keygen` to `cat`. But we need to pass the output of `cat` to `ssh-keygen`:

```
# using multiline here doc
$ cat <<EOF | ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048
/tmp/id_rsa    
/tmp/id_rsa.pub
password
EOF
```

OR

```
$ echo -e "/tmp/id_rsa\n/tmp/id_rsa.pub" | ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048
```

But use it with caution, this just feeds the entire input to the piped command. Depending on how that command processes input this might fail if the expected input is different from what is being piped in.

It may be fine for simple scripts/commands (will NOT work for ssh-keygen reliably in all cases [because it seems to spawn another process in some cases to ask for the passphrase]).

ref. https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html for heredoc